# The correct way of starting off functions on Firebase Cloud Functions while not waiting for them to return

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My code which looks something like the following:

```
exports.onRecordCreated = functions.database.ref('/' + postsFireRealtimeRef + '/{someId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
    }).then(someParameter => {
        return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
    }).then(someParameter => {
        return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
    }).then(someParameter => {
        return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
    });
```

I believe this implementation follows the [developer guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) by chaining all asynchronous operations and returning a promise. However, the problem is with this approach, that I don't want to wait for those `someFunctionReturningAPromise(..)` functions to finish (mainly because they take too long and I have a user to return to in a flow on the front-end). I'd rather send these functions on their way to do their things and return a resolved promise.

So I would do something like this:

```
exports.onRecordCreated = functions.database.ref('/' + postsFireRealtimeRef + '/{someId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        doWork();
        return true  // Tell front end that the server was reached ok with the record being created, but don't wait for all asynchronous operations to complete
    });

function doWork() {
    return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter)
        .then(someParameter => {
            return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
        }).then(someParameter => {
            return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
        }).then(someParameter => {
            return someFunctionReturningAPromise(someParameter);
        });
}
```

With this solution **I am concerned about the Firebase instance shutting down my 'rogue' function**. I don't know If I can get any guarantee that the `doWork()` function would be allowed to run, as according to Firebase:

> By terminating functions correctly ... can make sure that the Cloud
>   Functions instance running your function does not shut down before
>   your function successfully reaches its terminating condition or state.

What is the correct way of running such independent functions on the top of Firebase clouds? Shall I wrap `doWork()` in a separate [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function returns without waiting on all of its promises to complete, there is an very good chance it will all be shut down before they finish.

If you need more time to execute the work in a function, increase its timeout in the [Cloud console](http://console.cloud.google.com/) for your project, [max is 9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout).  If you need more than 9 minutes, you should split up your work and kick them off using a pub/sub trigger.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `res.send()` will send an immediate HTTP response without stopping your script execution. This script execution is only dependent on the timeout config value of your function.

Anyway, you shouldn't send multiple HTTP responses so, if you send a response before the script has ended, you need to implement some other way to report failures. Notification for example.